# Draw filled circle with a certain color

Tags: octave

How to draw a filled circle in GNU Octave with a certain color? I managed to do it with `DrawShape("circle", [center_x center_y radius], "fill")` but I couldn't change the color of the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a look at the implementation of [`drawShape`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/geometry/function/drawShape.html), e.g. by using `edit drawShape`, we see, that a combination of

- [`circleAsPolygon`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/geometry/function/circleAsPolygon.html),
- [`drawPolygon`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/geometry/function/drawPolygon.html), and
- [`fillPolygon`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/geometry/function/fillolygon.html)

is used, but unfortunately there's no passing of additional "plot parameters", like there's for [`drawCircle`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/geometry/function/drawCircle.html) for example. Latter method doesn't support filling. So, I'm afraid, for custom color filled circles, we need some indiviual code, like so:

```matlab
% Set up circle parameters
center_x = 0;
center_y = 0;
radius = 1;

% Calculate circle polygon coordinates
nVertices = 72;
coords = circleAsPolygon([center_x, center_y, radius]);

% Draw and fill circle polygon with desired color
drawPolygon(coords(:, 1), coords(:, 2), 'c');
fillPolygon(coords(:, 1), coords(:, 2), 'c');
xlim([-2 2]);
ylim([-2 2]);
axis equal;
```

This will produce such an output:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!